# How to find step definitions in java cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, build-automation, cucumber-jvm

I am using `cucumber-jvm` and have written some `BDD` tests using `gherkin`.
I'd like to create some sort of a dictionary that seraches for a given word and offers step definitions and the files containing those step definitions

Comment: Do you use an ide for programming? is the included search function not sufficent?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ack-grep](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/ack/ack#Why_is_it_called_ack_if_it's_called_ack-grep?) on mint linux. I set the following function:

```
function step {
 ack-grep -i "(@Given|@When|@Then|@And).+$*" --java
}
```

then call it like so to find steps with calendar in the text:

```
step calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load your step definitions classes and use reflection to analyse the annotations.
Something like this

```
    for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Given.class)) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());

            }
        }
```

Load the method names in a custom dictionnary to search into.

Comment: Not that you should load all the anotations (depending on your langage ...)